# I am getting very minimal mse values and not sure if it is correct?

Tags: linear-regression, prediction, accuracy, mse

Below is the linear regression model I fitted and not sure if I am doing the right way as I am getting neat to 99% accuracy

### Fitting Simple Linear Regression to the Training set

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

ln_regressor = LinearRegression()
mse = cross_val_score(ln_regressor, X_train, Y_train , scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5)
mean_mse = np.mean(mse)
print(mean_mse)

ln_regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)

** MSE SCORE =-6.612466691367042e-06**
```

### Predicting the Test set results

```
y_pred = ln_regressor.predict(X_test)
```

### Evaluating accuracy of test data

```
mse2 = cross_val_score(ln_regressor, X_test, y_pred , scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5)
mean_mse2 = np.mean(mse2)
print(mean_mse2)

**MSE score = -4.645751512870382e-31**
```

Please Note:
My data is in log scale & transformed to standard scaling later on

R2= cross_val_score(ln_regressor,X_test, y_pred,cv = 10)

R2.mean()

**R2 mean is '0.9999030728571852'**

Comment: As @plpopk said, you are training a regression problem and use a regression metric but use the word accuracy, this can be confusing to some. Your code seems fine, what does your data look like?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am new to this field.

Comment: My data looks fine, my predicted variable is close to testing variable and that is what is shocking on how did I achieve such results on my first model and do not want to continue my mistakes if I have done any.

Comment: I have added my Rsquare value using cross val score, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

So first thing first, accuracy is a classification concept. You can't say you have 99% accuracy for a regression problem.

Your code seems ok. Cross validation is not necessary here since you are not doing any hyper-parameter tuning or model selection. The mse error is indeed low, so I would suggest you go back to normalize your data, since if your target $y$ has a very small span, i.e. low $\sigma$ in Gaussian case, you will get a meaningless low mse guaranteed.

Comment: Cross-validation is absolutely fine to use in this case. It's merely a tool to get a good estimate of performance.

Comment: So to clarify by "Cross validation is not necessary" I mean the cross_val_score function used. Test cv is of course necessary, but if no model selection or hyper-parameter tuning was done then there is no need to do 5 fold cv.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. What does the `cross_val_score` function do that you deem unnecessary in this case?

Comment: @plpopk  My data is a normalized one, I have fitted it into the model after the log transformation and feature engineering

Comment: @ValentinCalomme Because I don't think `np.mean(cross_val_score(5_fold_cv_mse))` would be anything different from `mse(y_hat, y)`

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I'm not saying they will have exactly the same value, since for `cross_val_score` sklearn would train lr model on each fold and then calculate mse. My point is it will do nothing different from simply check mse over whole train dataset, because there is already a test set to see if lr is overfitting.

Comment: @yathislax Either you got a simple task or you got a problematic dataset then.

Comment: I kindly suggest you end your 2nd sentence at "*for a regression problem*"; the "*unless [...]*" part is irrelevant, borderline wrong (as written), and can be highly confusing, especially for beginners.

Comment: @desertnaut I agree.

Comment: @plpopk if it is a problematic data how are my predictions correct, this scares me

Comment: @yathislax An example is your `y` got included in `X` in upstream processing of your data. You might want to provide more context if you feel a perfect linear relation is not reliable.